# Return a value from a nested success function in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, nested-function

I'm trying to return a value from a nested function on my codes but it return me undefined whenever i tried to display it. This is my codes:

```
var calculateAlbum = function (albumPath,albumName) {
            return photoService.getPhotos(albumPath,albumName)
                    .success(function (data){                       
                        var status = data.myphotos.status;
                            if(status == "ok"){
                                    photoService.myphotosPhotoList()
                                        .success(function(data){
                                            $scope.allPhotoListTotal = {};
                                            var getAllPhotoList = data.config.nas_sharing;
                                            $scope.allPhotoListTotal = getAllPhotoList.count;
                                        });
                            }
                    });                 
    }
```

Return a value:

```
calculateAlbum(albumPath,fileName).then(function(data) {            
                            var gettotal = $scope.allPhotoListTotal;
                            console.log(gettotal);

                        });
```

After returning value in a console. It send me undefined. What is the best approached for this?

Comment: You need to read up on promises in angular. What is most likely happening is that you are trying to use a value before your async request has resolved. Basically, you're trying to spend money before you get paid.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to return the promise of `photoService.myphotosPhotoList`.

You also forgot to reject the first promise when status is not ok (you can test out this case).

```
function calculateAlbum (albumPath,albumName) {
    return photoService.getPhotos(albumPath,albumName)
        .then(function (data){                       
            var status = data.myphotos.status;

            if(status == "ok") {
                return photoService.myphotosPhotoList()
                    .then(function(data){
                        $scope.allPhotoListTotal = {};
                        var getAllPhotoList = data.config.nas_sharing;
                        $scope.allPhotoListTotal = getAllPhotoList.count;
                    });
            }
            else {
                return $q.reject("status not ok");
            }
       });                 
}
```

Comment: when i changed success to then.. status became undefined even i used to define it already. So i bring it back to success but still resulted me to undefined.

Comment: @Amboom After a long search in google I can't find an example of using `.success` which is not from the `$http` service. Can you modify this [fiddle](http://jsbin.com/xoragofigi/1/edit?html,js,output) so that it uses `.success` instead of `.then`? Or better, you can change your function so it uses `.then` instead.

Comment: i just used a custom service to return my $http: `photoService.myphotosPhotoList()`.. But anyway i really appreciate your effort to help me.. It's working now with all of your help.. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. Although it feels satisfying to solve others' problems, but it is more so if I can show you the best practice in the same time. It's a more common practice to use `.then` instead of `.success` in angular world (you can search `then vs success` in google). Feel free to ask any further question related to promise.

Answer (score 1):

You have two promises in your code, but you are only chaining off of the first (outer) promise. Your inner promise sets the value that you want, therefore you need to wait for your inner promise to resolve before you can use it.

One approach would be to inject the promise service `$q` and then return your own promise object.

```
var calculateAlbum = function (albumPath,albumName) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        photoService.getPhotos(albumPath,albumName)
                .success(function (data){                       
                    var status = data.myphotos.status;
                        if(status == "ok"){
                                photoService.myphotosPhotoList()
                                    .success(function(data){
                                        var getAllPhotoList = data.config.nas_sharing;
                                        $scope.allPhotoListTotal = getAllPhotoList.count;
                                        deferred.resolve(data)
                                    });
                        }
                });
        return deferred.promise;


}
```

Answer (score 1):

calculateAlbum returns a `promise` that is fulfilled when the outer call finishes, but it doesn't take into account the inner execution. you need to return a `promise` inside the inner success function in order to wait for another async method. Here we leverate the power of `$q` to do exactly that.

```
var calculateAlbum = function (albumPath,albumName) {
        return photoService.getPhotos(albumPath,albumName)
                .success(function (data){                       
                    var status = data.myphotos.status;
                    var defer = $q.defer();
                        if(status == "ok"){
                                photoService.myphotosPhotoList()
                                    .success(function(data){
                                        $scope.allPhotoListTotal = {};
                                        var getAllPhotoList = data.config.nas_sharing;
                                        $scope.allPhotoListTotal = getAllPhotoList.count;
                                        defer.resolve(); //Async execution end here
                                    })
                                    .error(defer.reject);
                        } 
                        else
                           defer.reject();
                     return defer.promise;
                });                 
}
```

Note: this is an anti-pattern but there's no other way since `photoService.myphotosPhotoList()` executes only some of the time.

Edit: there is other way actually. have a look at icycool's solution

Comment: You can return the inner promise so the outer one would only resolve when the inner one resolve: [example](http://jsbin.com/xoragofigi/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: I know that, I didn't know you can use `$q.reject/resolve` without a defer instance though.